# Base tables already exist

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.9.1.0, upgrade, php-5.4, database-update

Hi guys I have been trying hard to upgrade a magento 1.3.2.4 to magento 1.7 but it is not playing ball: it keeps saying that the base tables already exists. In particular these are: index_event, index_process_event and etc. I have attempted the following but no luck.

Go to the core_resource table and update the version values with the ones shown in the report trace. But this just then goes onto the next error.

Go to the relevant sql file and add a drop if exists line. But, now it is just stuck on the report page, whilst the tab shows connecting with the activity circle spinning.

Please help!!!!! I just want to get the magento upgraded. I'd not fussed about no theme or anything. I have made a new theme in 1.9 which will be used once this magento has been upgraded. I just want to keep order history, product info, and customer info.

UPDATE:

I have managed to get it to 1.7, but now orders aren't showing up in backend. all blank ? why could this be ?

Likewise going over to manage customers I get the error:

```
 Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/customer/customer_address" already exists

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/html/www.librex.co.uk/fresh/magento1.7/app/Mage.php(518): Mage::register('_resource_singl...', false)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Type.php(328): Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/custom...')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php(428): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type->getEntity()
#4 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(384): Mage_Eav_Model_Config->getAttribute(Object(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type), 'city')
#5 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(649): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->getAttribute('city')
#6 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php(54): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_addres...', 'default_billing', NULL, 'left')
#7 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#8 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#10 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#12 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#13 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/w...')
#15 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#24 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#25 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/w...')
#26 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(83): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->indexAction()
#34 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}
```

solved this :

I looked at eav_entity_type table. And noticed in entity_model field value is customer/customer_address where entity_type_code is customer_address. This value should be customer/address, changed it.

But now, I get:

```
Invalid backend model specified: customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_region
```

okay so that has also been fixed, but now get a white screen when I try edit a product. Likewise, the default theme in magento 1.7 isn't appearing to display properly. Why could this be ?

Comment: Does it say what is the setup file generating this error?

Comment: @RiccardoT install-1.6.0.0.php.

Comment: install-1.6.0.0.php is too generic, please pase the path of that file

Comment: /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Index/sql/index_setup

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting all the code lines in:
    /var/www/html/magento/fresh/magento1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Index/sql/index_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php

You poroblably already run it and it is trying to create exising tables.

Comment: did that pal, but it didn't work. currently  using the db repair tool with a fresh install of 1.7 to see if this helps.

Comment: Your problem is not there. You are going to mess it up with an half installed Magento and a recovery procedure. It must work, please make sure you do not have a different error.

Comment: Column "cost" does not exists on table "sales_flat_order_item" is the latest error, so ive took an fresh install of 1.7 and ran it on that db. this mean I have to add the column ?

Comment: Actually it means you really messed up your db for some reason I do not know. Anyway, yes, you have to add it and try solving errors as you sse them.

Comment: it was a simple case of amending the values in the core_resource table, which has done the trick. I have got it to 1.7. But my sales data ain't there! Does order history and so forth get wiped ?

Comment: If you change the core_resource you manually change the version value, but you do not run the install scripts.

Comment: So I shouldn't have ran the installation ?

Comment: It is hard to say what is going on if you manually modified the core_resource table. I suggest you to restore a DB backup.

Comment: not to worry, I am going to roll it back to 1.3.2.4 again and then incrementally take it up to 1.6.2 and then 1.9

Comment: I went back to my old db, and attempted to upgrade to 1.4.1.1 but no luck, as it just gets stuck on some redirect loop error for a bizzare reason. So, again I went and ran the repair tool which shows my database as having no errors (compared with a fresh 1.4.1.1 install db). But, no orders come through again!!